# Is it possible to include a .bib file inside another one?

Tags: bibtex

When I started writing documents I decided to use a single `.bib` file in the main document directory. Each document would be created in a subdirectory and terminate with

```
\bibliography{../biblio} 
\end{document}
```

I now realize that this might not have been the smartest choice, as my `.bib` file is growing considerably.

In an attempt to avoid being forced to fix all my `.tex` files, I would like to know if it is possible to include other `.bib` files (e.g., one for articles, one for book, one for urls, etc.) from inside the "main" one.

Or if you have other suggestions that would avoid me such tedious (but probably deserved) task.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The short answer to your question is no. As @daleif mentioned in the comments, the `.bib` file format doesn't have an input-like function or field. The `.bib` file format is just a series of field identifiers, such as `@BOOK` and `@ARTICLE`, as well as the `@PREAMBLE` and `@STRING` fields. The [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/biblio/bibtex/base/btxhak.pdf) for the actual `bibtex` postfix language doesn't make any mention of an input function either (as far as I can find). It seems that `bibtex` is hard-coded just to fetch the bib data from the `.aux` file, so the only way for a document to access references over multiple `.bib` files is to specify them as a comma-separated list in the argument of `\bibliography`.

The only solution I can suggest for your problem is to write a short script that will perform a search and replace of `\bibliography{../biblio}` with `\bibliography{file1,file2,etc}`. How to do this depends on the tools you have available on your computer. For example, on a Unix-like system, you could probably combine `find` with `sed`. For a more platform-independent approach, a scripting language, such as Perl, could be used.

However, if you're simply finding it cumbersome to edit a large `.bib` file in a text editor, you may prefer to use a reference manager such as JabRef.